# Como comparar duas colunas e retornar a soma?

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows, tabela-html, planilha, microsoft-office

Fala pessoal,

Tenho a seguinte tabela abaixo, o que eu quero é que ele some o **Preço** (Coluna D) de todos os livros que estão com a **Situação** (Coluna E) *"Vendido"*.

Sei que dá para fazer com a função PROCV. Mas já estou a horas estudando essa função e até agora eu não consegui implementar na minha tabela. Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei extremamente grato.

No mais, agradeço a atenção e compreensão do problema.

[image: Minha Tabela]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dá uma olhada nessa função `SOMASE` [Aqui](https://www.aprenderexcel.com.br/2013/artigos/como-fazer-soma-condicional-no-excel)

```
=SOMASE(E2:E22, "Vendido", D2:D22)
```

Comment: Nossa, mais fácil do que eu pensava. Muito obrigado, Willys!